# How can I add pre-defined fields / checklists etc to all cards created in a board in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have an use case where I need each card created in a board to have a predefined checklist, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible in a future version using an API or plug-in.

In general, if there's something that needs to be done for every card on a board, that idea maps more closely to the card being in a given list than having a pre-defined checklist.  I understand that this doesn't allow for, say, two out of three tasks having been done. But we want to keep Trello as simple as possible, so this isn't built-in for the time being.

Comment: Rich's answer is correct at the moment, and there is a conversation on this topic happening on the [Trello Development board](https://trello.com/card/board/make-checklists-re-usable/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e1e0ab1802ec6e81c0ee19c).